# Google Sheets Auto Time Stamp

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

My script quit working for google sheets.  I can't see why line 7 is hanging up.

Here is the script

```
function onEdit(event)
{ 
  var timezone = "GMT-7";
  var timestamp_format = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss";
  var updateColName = "Narrative";
  var timeStampColName = "Time Stamp";
  var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName('Narrative'); 


  var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
  var headers = sheet.getRange(2, 2, 2, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName);
  var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName); updateCol = updateCol+1;
  if (dateCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == updateCol) {
    var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1);
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);
    cell.setValue(date);
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked in the execution transcript? You can also set your notifications to immediate.

Answer (score 0):

Has the name of the sheet changed?

```
var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName('Narrative');
```

Comment: No it is still called narrative.  It seems that 'source' is hanging it up.  Might it be possible that google changed it available commands?